# Passing a value to extjs textfield using jquery

Tags: jquery, extjs

I am trying to use a jquery datepicker for an extjs 4.2 textfield. The calendar is opening and i am able to select a date however the selected value is not displayed inside the textfield. Any help please?

```
 Date_Range = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 480,
        id:'Date_Range',
        border:false,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            id:'from',
            name: 'from_date',
            handler:Ext.onReady(function(){
                       $("#from").calendarsPicker({calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic'),
                       showTrigger: '<img src="icon/calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger">',
                       showOnFocus: false});
                        $("#from").calendarsPicker({showTrigger: '#myicon'});
                      })
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a jquery datepicker instead of extjs datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an id to an ExtJS element; it doesn't appear exactly what you named it. For instance, the `form` id in your code is converted to `form-inputEl`.
So, if you use `form-inputEl` in your jquery selector you can access the element.

In fact, ExtJS wraps the actual input element with some other elements, it is the reason that you can not access the input element by its id.